# Is it a Basel-type problem, or what?

Tags: sequences-and-series

I conjecture that $\sum_{k=-\infty}^\infty \exp(-(x-k)^2/2)=\sqrt{2\pi}$, for any real value of $x$. This is a shock, because this is a discretization of the celebrated normal curve, hence no reason that it works out as above. I have $\$50$ in cash for the first solver, even if it is well-known. I just want to be certain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By the Poisson summation formula,
$$\sum_{k=-\infty}^\infty\exp\left(-\frac{(x-k)^2}2\right)
=\sqrt{2\pi}\sum_{r=-\infty}^\infty\exp(2\pi i rx)
\exp\left(-2\pi^2 r^2\right).$$
This is a well-known theta function identity. Of course $\exp(-2\pi^2)$
is quite small, so for real $x$ this is close to, but not equal to
$\sqrt{2\pi}$.

Comment: Actually, my real question is if we can make $\sum_{k=-\infty}^\infty \exp(-(x-k)^2/2d^2)$ to be constant, for a proper $d$ value (which should be close to 1, by your answer). Anyway, thanks, send your mailing address to dbenko2016@yahoo.com to get the money.

Comment: @Dave The answer to that is no.